# C# Copy substring of a string then put it before the next word of the string

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy the last character of every word of a string then put the copied character to first position of the next word. For example, if I enter the string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", the output should be "The equick kbrown nfox xjumps sover rthe elazy ydog";

Here is what I have so far:

```
string s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

for (int a = 0; a < s.Length; a++)
{
    string b = s.Substring(a,1);
    if (b == " ")
    {
        string c = s.Substring(a - 1, 1);
        string d = s.Insert (a+1, c);
        Console.Write(d);                     
    }                
}
```

The result of this is this :
The equick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick kbrown fox jumps over the
lazy dogThe quick brown nfox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox xjumps o
ver the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps sover the lazy dogThe quick brown fox
jumps over rthe lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the elazy dogThe quick br
own fox jumps over the lazy ydog

What I am trying to achieve is this output "The equick kbrown nfox xjumps sover rthe elazy ydog"

Thanks to all who answered by the way :)

Comment: And the problem is… shall we guess or will you complete the question?

Comment: Start by looking at `StringBuilder`. In your code you _throw away_ `c` and `d` at every iteration, never changing `s`.

Comment: Strings index their characters, so instead of `s.Substring(a,1)` you can just use `s[a]` instead.

Comment: I am trying to insert the last character of every word of a string and put it to the first postion of the next word. Like, "Hello World" -> "Hello oWorld" I ran my program but I got 8 lines of answer instead of a single line. This is what it looks The equick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick kbrown fox jumps over the
lazy dogThe quick brown nfox jumps over the lazy dogThe quick brown fox xjumps o
ver the lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps sover the lazy dogThe quick brown fox
jumps over rthe lazy dogThe quick brown fox jumps over the elazy dogThe quick br
own fox jumps over the lazy yd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
string s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

char lastChar = default(char);
bool addLastChar = false;
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s);
for (int i = 0; i < stringBuilder.Length; i++)
{
    var ch = stringBuilder[i];

    // TODO: consider using char.IsWhiteSpace(ch) method call.
    // Please note: it will return true for different whitespace characters (tabulation, line feed, carriage return, etc).
    if (ch == ' ')
    {
        addLastChar = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (addLastChar)
        {
            stringBuilder.Insert(i, lastChar);
            addLastChar = false;
        }

        lastChar = ch;
    }
}

var result = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

The code also works fine for strings with more than one space in the middle, like this:

```
string s = "The    quick    brown   fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

Comment: Side.note: use [`Char.IsWhiteSpace(ch)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) instead of `ch == ' '`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thank you for the note. Interesting thing: `char.IsWhiteSpace('\t')` returns true (also, it returns true for `\r, \n`).

Comment: Yes, look at the remarks for the list of white-space characters.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, good, I've added the information about this method call as a comment. I think we should let the OP choose the condition to check.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
string[] words = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Split();
string res = String.Join(" ", words.Select((w, i) => i == 0 ? w : words[i-1].Last() + w));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/lKLKqt)

```
The equick kbrown nfox xjumps sover rthe elazy ydog
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new string (`d`) where you insert a single character, print it and forget it.

What you could do:

- split the string into words
- change the words
- combine them to a new string

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = s.Split(' ').Where(x=>x!="").ToArray();
var str = "";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for(var i = 0; i< words.Lenght;i++)
{
    sb.Append(str);
    sb.Append(words[i]);
    sb.Append(" ");
    str = words[words.Lenght - 1].ToString();
}

var result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: `String.Split()` does not accept a `char` as argument; it needs a `char[]`

Comment: @Nolonar wellcome to .net programing http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/b873y76a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?ppud=4

Comment: Okay, my bad. Didn't know what `params` did

Answer (score 0):

The answer is relatively easy, you can split your string using

```
string[] sArray = s.Split(new char[]{' '});
```

Then iterate through the array

```
for (int i = 1; i < sArray.Length; i++)
{
    sArray[i] = sArray[i - 1].Substring(sArray[i - 1].Length) + sArray[i];
}
s = string.Join(" ", sArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this.

```
string S= "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
                var splitString = S.Split(' ');
                string newS = splitString[0];
                for(int i=1;i<splitString.Length;i++)
                {
                    splitString[i] = splitString[0].ElementAt(splitString[0].Length) + splitString[i];
                    newS += " " + splitString[i];
                }
                Console.WriteLine(newS);
```